# Trying to make a line plot with multiple lines, but get an empty plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So, I'm wanting to graph this baseball player's batting average, on base percentage, slugging percentage, and on base plus slugging on one graph across the years 2017-2022. The dataframe has the years, then the aforementioned statistics in that same order. My code for the line plot is this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(slashline, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BA), color = "BA") +
  geom_line(aes(y = OBP), color = "OBP") +
  geom_line(aes(y = SLG), color = "SLG") +
  geom_line(aes(y = OPS), color = "OPS")
```

From what I've seen, this should work, but instead it just plots BA, OBP, SLG, and OPS on the Y axis and doesn't plot any numbers or actual data, and so the lines obviously don't show up either. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: So thanks to the answer from Moliz, I was able to get most of the problem solved. Here is my code thus far:

```
happData <- read_csv("my pathfile")

slashline <- happData %>% 
select(Year, "BA", "OBP", "SLG", "OPS")

slashline <- slashline[-c(7, 8),]

slashline2 <- slashline %>% 
gather(key="type",value="value",BA,OBP,SLG,OPS)
slashline2

# Here's the code for the graph
ggplot(slashline2,aes(x=Year,y= value,color=type))+
geom_point()+
geom_line(alpha = .5)+
labs(y = "",
   title = "Ian Happ's Statistics, 2017-2022",
   key = "")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
guides(color = guide_legend(title = ""))+
scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Batting Average", "On-Base Percentage", 
"Slugging Percentage", "On-Base Plus Slugging"))
```

Here's the output for this graph:

[Ian Happ Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVHZb.png)

Obviously, the problem is that there's no lines to connect the dots even though there should be. I'm not really sure why this is. When I plug in group = 1, it makes the graph messy with lines going all over the place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a sample of data by editing your question to include the output of running `dput(head(slashline))`?

Answer (score 2):

Following your description I created a random dataset.

```
year <- 2017:2022
BA <- runif(6,0,1)
OBP <- runif(6,0,1)
SLG <- runif(6,0,1)
OPS <- runif(6,0,1)
df <- data.frame(year,BA,OBP,SLG,OPS)
df
```

`runif(6,0,1)` draws 6 random numbers from 0 to 1 according to a uniform distribution.

I think this is what your dataset looks like.

```
  year        BA        OBP        SLG        OPS
1 2017 0.1915609 0.03188816 0.57335645 0.64135658
2 2018 0.5832220 0.11446759 0.44750805 0.52573932
3 2019 0.4594732 0.46893548 0.08380201 0.03928139
4 2020 0.4674340 0.39698674 0.21913855 0.54585984
5 2021 0.3998326 0.83361919 0.07557029 0.37276310
6 2022 0.5052856 0.76112174 0.53442678 0.96130241
```

But now we need to make a little change. Here you need to library `tidyr` package and use `gather()` function:
[How to use gather function](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html)

```
df2 <- df %>% gather(key="type",value="value",BA,OBP,SLG,OPS)
df2
```

```
 year type      value
1  2017   BA 0.19156087
2  2018   BA 0.58322197
3  2019   BA 0.45947319
4  2020   BA 0.46743405
5  2021   BA 0.39983256
6  2022   BA 0.50528560
7  2017  OBP 0.03188816
8  2018  OBP 0.11446759
9  2019  OBP 0.46893548
10 2020  OBP 0.39698674
11 2021  OBP 0.83361919
12 2022  OBP 0.76112174
13 2017  SLG 0.57335645
14 2018  SLG 0.44750805
15 2019  SLG 0.08380201
16 2020  SLG 0.21913855
17 2021  SLG 0.07557029
18 2022  SLG 0.53442678
19 2017  OPS 0.64135658
20 2018  OPS 0.52573932
21 2019  OPS 0.03928139
22 2020  OPS 0.54585984
23 2021  OPS 0.37276310
24 2022  OPS 0.96130241
```

Finally use `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=year,y=value,color=type))+geom_point()+geom_line(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

(Because I did not set the random number seed and re-run the code, so here `df2` is not the same as described above)

You can run the above code on your computer and verify that the output image meets your requirements. <3

Comment: Oh wow, this was almost perfect. I appreciate the help! The only thing missing is the geom_line() function doesn't return the connected dots. As of now the graph is just a bunch of dots. Any ideas?

Comment: @pcm1113 I apologize for not answering in time. I successfully ran the above code and get the output of `geom_line()`and `geom_point()`. In response to your question, perhaps examining the output would get more detailed information?

Comment: Hmm. I run the exact same code basically, and I get "`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" I've tried to fix this by putting group = 1 in a bunch of different places but nothing seems to work. I'll post the output in an edit

Comment: Maybe this article can help you. ["Why ggplot2 geom_line() does not draw lines?"](https://www.drdataking.com/post/why-ggplot2-geom-line-does-not-draw-lines/) You can use `str()` to check if `Year` in your dataset is `int` instead of `str`.

Comment: It says Year is a character variable. So I tried converting it to a string and nothing happened, so I'm not really sure what to do anymore.

Comment: I ran the code you subsequently provided and got the dotted line plot. So I guess the possible reason is not the ggplot2 code but your dataset. The reason I can guess at this point is that although you converted the `Year` class of `slashline`, you did not convert `slashline2` which is based on `slashline`. Or better yet, check `slashline` as well as `slashline2` to make sure `Year` is `int` and run whole code again.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I just don't know how to convert the Year variable into an integer, but I've tried as.integer(slashline$Year), and then saw what type of variable it is with the class() function and the str() function, and both say they're character variables even after I've run the as.integer code. Keep in mind I haven't done it for the slashline2 one yet since I can't even get it working for the original slashline. Can I send you the dataset I'm using and the full code I have thus far and you can analyze it? If not, I understand, but I feel that that's the best way.

Comment: @pcm1113 First of all, thank you very much for your trust in me! But ethically you can't share data with strangers unless you are the administrator of the data and have approval from others. Check this:

`slashline$Year <- as.integer(slashline$Year)`: whether to save the result of the conversion to `slashline`.

Comment: Oh my goodness it finally worked. I appreciate your help so, so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

"BA", "OBP"... are not color code, should be put inside `aes()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(slashline, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BA, color = "BA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = OBP, color = "OBP")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SLG, color = "SLG")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = OPS, color = "OPS"))
```

Without your example data, I cannot test it on my side but I am pretty sure this should work unless there are issues with data.